# Intermittent Microsoft Azure Web Site access failure

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a number of small MVC apps deployed as Microsoft Windows Azure websites.  This has been working for several months.

Yesterday I rolled out a new one, and the deployment was unremarkable, everything worked fine.  But a couple of hours later, access to the site was unavailable.  The symptoms were that when the browser tried to navigate to the URL for that site, it would try to load for several minutes and then just give up with a completely blank page.

I attempted to stop and restart the site, and it worked once, but the symptoms came back several minutes later.  Then I tried to stop and restart, and it didn't work.

I deployed the identical app to three additional URLs.  Again, immediately on deployment, they all work fine, however, they fail at some interval in the future.  They seem to not all fail at once.  Sometimes restarting the site will fix the problem, and sometimes not.

IMPORTANT:  If I wait for some period of time, the site may start to work again on its own.

However, deploying four versions of the app so that our users can go to a backup one if the primary one is not working is not optimal.

Any words of wisdom as to how I might go about debugging this?

ADDITIONAL INFO NOV 25, 2013:
When sites are failing, the IIS logs show either 500 or 502 Internal Service Errors.  Our own MVC code is never hit, not even app_start.

Comment: I am seeing the same problem.  I am running a website in azure and once in a while I start seeing 500 and 502 errors in the webserver logs.  It never even reaches my webapi code when its getting these errors, because I see nothing in the application logs.  Has anyone figured out what causes this in azure?

Answer (score 0):

You can start by checking the logs and remote debugging

http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/azure-sdk-22-supports-visual-studio-2013/240163499

Are the apps working locally?

Comment: Apps are working locally just fine.  And when delivered under azure, also work just fine.  I can exercise the hell out of them -- and once I have a session to the MVC app on Azure, it never bails out while working.  It is only when I am coming back after a time away (likely expired session) that the app just is not served.  I'll check out the remote debugging idea.

Comment: Debugger is cool, and I like it, but it isn't helping me with this issue.  My own code is never getting hit... When sites are failing, the IIS logs show either 500 or 502 Internal Service Errors.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the same problem, but from time to time our Azure instances will get the blue question mark of death as a status.

The reason we found out was that Microsoft will do upgrades on instances from time to time. If you have just one instance in a cloud service/role, then from time to time they will do maintenance and during that time it will be *dead*.

I have confirmed this with their support.

The only way to get around this that I know of is to create two instances. Then Microsoft guarantees ~99% availability.

Of course I also confirmed with them that this means twice the cost. =/

If that's not the issue I would enable RDP and get onto the machine to see what the problem is. Microsoft has these tools to help debug problems: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx

Comment: We are working in the lower-rent shared Azure Web Site space, so we don't have access to a VM to RDP to... at least at present.  If we continue to run into this kind of issue, we may need to change that, but we are not needing any functionality that doesn't exist in the shared environment, and enjoying (until we hit bugs like this) not being responsible for the IT side....

Answer (score 0):

First, you should always run multiple instances of your web role with more than 1 upgrade domain.  This is configurable in the service definition (CSDEF).  Without this, you don't get an SLA from Microsoft, so you can't really complain that the VMs go down.

Second, to figure out what might be going on with these boxes, you should have both logs (my preference is to roll my own with page blobs or table storage), AND you should always have RDP access to a pre-production environment (production as well if you're not too fussed about security).  Once on the box, look through the event viewer for errors.

Third, when an outage occurs check out the azure service dashboard (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/support/service-dashboard/) for outages.

Lastly, contact Microsoft support.  It may take a few hours, but they are pretty good.

That it is happening repeatedly and for extended periods of time (more than 5 minutes), I would be there's something wrong with your hosted service.  Again, RDP in and poke around.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas on this.  Service dashboard is a great find, although that does not seem to be our issue.  I can't RDP -- currently the apps are Azure Websites, and do not reside on any machine to which we have console access.  As such, I don't think there is a concept of a web role or upgrade domain.... although maybe I am missing some key concept here?

Answer (score 0):

To debug your sites try to enable diagnostic logs:
http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics-logging-and-instrumentation/

Another nice way to look around your site is using the debug console:
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console

Comment: When sites are failing, the IIS logs show either 500 or 502 Internal Service Errors.  Our own MVC code is never hit, not even app_start.

Comment: Are those free sites? is it possible you run out of CPU allowed? You can check that in the website's dashboard.